# cloud big table adds an additional / when setting a hex value

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I am trying to set a value in cloud big table using the terminal "cbt". The values are in hex and for some reason it adds an additional / when I submit it. I want it to look like

```
='\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

but it looks like

```
 "\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00"
```

I have tried to use single quotes `'`,adding a slash before `/\x00` both of which do not work.

How can I set `'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'` as my value using cbt?